# Angular 4 lazy loading components with separate imported modules not loading. No console errors

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I am working to lazy load each page of my Angular component. But I am having some issues: when the page loads, the screen is just blank with no console errors or anything... I am trying to use one module per reusable component but doing this is causing the issue.

app.component.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LocalStorageModule } from 'angular-2-local-storage';
import { AuthHttp, provideAuth } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { MAIN_SITE_ROUTES } from './app.routes';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(MAIN_SITE_ROUTES),
    LocalStorageModule.withConfig({
       prefix: 'my-app',
       storageType: 'localStorage'
    })
  ],
  declarations: [
    // main component
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthHttp,
    provideAuth({
      headerName: 'Authorization',
      headerPrefix: 'bearer',
      tokenName: 'token',
      tokenGetter: (() => localStorage.getItem('id_token')),
      globalHeaders: [{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }],
      noJwtError: true
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const MAIN_SITE_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './mainSite/pages/home/home.module#HomeModule'},
  { path: 'about', loadChildren: './mainSite/pages/about/about.module#AboutModule'},
]
```

home.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { HOME_ROUTES } from "./home.routes";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
import { HomeService } from "./home.service";

import { SettingsAdminService } from '../../../adminSite/pages/settings/settings.service';
import { PageSetupService } from '../../../services/pageSetup';
import { UtilitiesService } from '../../../services/utilities';

import { LoaderModule } from "../../../sharedComponents/loader/loader.component";
import { ErrorModule } from "../../../sharedComponents/error/error.component";
import { ChangeNoticeModule } from "../../../sharedComponents/changeNotice/change-notice.component";
import { AdminModalModule } from "../../../sharedComponents/modal/admin-modal.component";
import { NavigationModule } from "../../../sharedComponents/navigation/navigation.component";


@NgModule({
    declarations: [HomeComponent],
    providers: [
        HomeService,
        SettingsAdminService,
        PageSetupService, 
        UtilitiesService
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        LoaderModule,
        ErrorModule,
        NavigationModule,
        ChangeNoticeModule,
        AdminModalModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(HOME_ROUTES)
    ]
})

export class HomeModule { }
```

Is there anything I'm missing to get the page to load???

Comment: first your `app.component.ts` looks  nothing like a component  it must be app.module.ts. make sure you export and import `@NgModule({  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],  exports: [RouterModule] })   export class AppRoutingModule {}` in app.routes.ts ( should have been app.routing.module.ts by  the way) and just import  `AppRoutingModule` to the `app.module.ts`

Comment: have you added `<router-outlet>` in `app.component.html` ?, also show the `HOME_ROUTES` array.